# How to append float in a text file in python?

Tags: python

So I'm a beginner in python and I was trying the append commands. It worked very well with strings but not with floats. I used this:

```
Num1 = float(input("Enter 1st num: "))
Num2 = float(input("Enter 2nd num: "))
Salary = num1 - num2
employee_file = open("employee_salary.txt", "a")
employee_file.write(salary)
employee_file.close()
```

I know I could just remove `float()` from input but that was just an example, my program in more complicated than that and I don't want to remove `float()`. Is there any command to append float to a text file?  Please help me.

Comment: See [What is the correct format to write float value to file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50893146/what-is-the-correct-format-to-write-float-value-to-file-in-python).

Comment: Text files are text. They contain strings. You can't write a float to a text file, only a string representation of a float.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to convert the float to a string first.

```
employee_file.write(str(salary))
```

Also, you might want to append a newline, as `File.write()` does not do that automatically.

```
employee_file.write(str(salary) + '\n')
```

---

Further, do not open and close files explicitely. It is considered better practice to do that with python's `with` construct:

```
num2 = float(input("Enter 2nd num: "))
salary = num1 - num2
with open("employee_salary.txt", "a") as employee_file:
    employee_file.write(str(salary) + '\n')
# No close necessary, the end of the with-paragraph closes the file automatically
```

Comment: That's not off-topic, but a good advice, I would remove the words in bold if I were you

Comment: Sure, if you think that's better.

Answer (score 0):

You could convert it to a string and then append, use [`str(x)`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/str) for that.

```py
Num2 = float(input("Enter 2nd num: "))
Salary = num1 - num2
employee_file = open("employee_salary.txt", "a")
employee_file.write(str(salary))
employee_file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your float to text to be able to write it to text file. If you are using Python 3.6 or newer you might use so-called f-strings. Just replace

```
employee_file.write(salary)
```

in your code with

```
employee_file.write(f"{salary}\n")
```

then it would always append salary and `newline` to your file. If you want to know more about f-strings I suggested reading [this article](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/). As side note I want to alert you that operations on `float`s might result in outcome, which is not correct from mathematical point of view, if you wish to read more about it [there is relevant documentation piece](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html). Due to this you might end with values less than 1 cent, in surprising places, consider following example:

```
s = 0.1+0.1+0.1
print(s)
```

Output:

```
0.30000000000000004
```